# Issues in splitting a string variable merged by hyphen using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to split a string variable joined by hyphen in AngularJS.

In JavaScript, this is what am trying to achieve:

```
var testing = "100-200-400";
var arr = testing.split("-");
alert(arr[0]);
alert(arr[1]);
alert(arr[2]);
```

Below is my script in AngularJS with the string I want to split:

```
app.controller('postCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.modal = [];
    $rootScope.data_send = {
        testing: "100-200-400",
    };
}]);
```

Can someone help me do it the same thing in my controller?

Comment: your string splitting code works fine, what's the issue in using it with AngularJS?

Comment: @ Omar i need to  use it in angularjs and not in Javascript.

Comment: did your mean how you split in controller ? you can use this code in angularjs controller after define your rootscope  `$scope.arr = $rootScope.data_send.testing.split("-");`  or `$rootScope.arr = $rootScope.data_send.testing.split("-");`

Comment: i will use it in my view.  i used to pass the variable to database. so i need to split the string before passing it database using nodejs

Comment: At Etibar, You are on the line. how do I pass the split string 100, 200, 400 as variable eg var1 =arr[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is still pretty much JavaScript, so you can do the same JS things in it.

You could store and access the returned array in `$scope`, like so:

```
$scope.arr = $rootScope.data_send.testing.split('-');
console.log($scope.arr[0]); // '100'
console.log($scope.arr[1]); // '200'
console.log($scope.arr[2]); // '400'
```

Or you can store it and access it in normal JS vars (won't be accessible in `$scope`), like so:

```
var arr = $rootScope.data_send.testing.split('-');
console.log(arr[0]); // '100'
console.log(arr[1]); // '200'
console.log(arr[2]); // '400'
```